# Stuttering in excited situations

Tags: united-states, conversations, stuttering

This doesn't happen often, but occasionally, when I get really excited about something, when I try to talk, I trip up on my words, stutter a bit, and what-not. I'm not even really sure why it happens, and it doesn't happen super often.

For example, once I got really excited about a physics book I was reading and was explaining part of it to a friend who is also interested in physics, and I started mixing up my words and stuttering. I think I also might have said a few words twice.

My friends are kind enough to look past it, but I'd like to try to stop doing it, in case I get that sort of excited in a not quite as friendly social situation.

How bad does stuttering look in a conversation of that sort, and how can I stop doing it?

Comment: I heard of/read about a method that focuses on breathing and the rythm of the sentence, a way to breath inbetween words, but can't find any link in english (so, not an answer). Any chance you're familiar with another language ?

Comment: @OldPadawan sorry, nope =/

Comment: @oldpadawan, I am Chinese and American with a huge stuttering info, do tell about your rhythm method.

Answer (score 6):

I believe I know where you're coming from, I often feel the same way.

This is what I do to stop myself:

1. Stop talking for a second or excuse yourself. Go in the other room, take a deep breath and focus on your surroundings. (These are mediation techniques)
2. Don't rush yourself when you talk, take time to think of the words you want to say. Finish your sentence before going to another topic. *It's ok to talk slowly.*
3. Ask yourself why this happens when it does. Maybe you really like the person you're talking to? Are you afraid of looking dumb, boring, silly? Work on this issue with yourself.
4. If you don't already, talk to more people. I find that if I've been a hermit all week, I'll stutter more upon going back to conversing. Talk to random people on the street, people around you, or call a friend. Do this just for practice. Finding words isn't always easy.
5. Be aware of how you feel physically. I'll fumble more when I have an empty belly and have drank caffeine.

Comment: Talk to other humans? Aloud? *::shudders::* =P Seriously, though, good answer, +1.

Comment: About the second point, I advise you the following: get into your room, read something from a book, and see how much time this took. Then read the same sentence again and again in the double amount of time. This will force you to slow down your speed.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers have focused on breathing that you can do to stop the stuttering so I'll skip that part.

Although that's great, sometimes I find it hard to do in the moment, especially if people are paying attention to me and expecting me to continue. In those cases, its good to buy yourself a bit of time by deflecting with humor. For example saying, "Wow, I'm so excited about this book I'm tripping over myself!" or "I'm so excited about it I can't speak straight!" This will automatically put your audience at ease, because you are addressing your stutter and not ignoring it, and will give you a few seconds to take a breath and start again.

It's also useful because if, slightly further into the conversation, you find yourself stuttering or tripping over words, you've already established the reason for it and can reiterate, "See, told you I was excited, tripping over myself again *haha*". It makes it less awkward for you and the other people in your conversation which in turn will make you feel more at ease and stutter less.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem, much worse than you however. I stuttered since I was small, and still do. Mostly when I want to say something long and fast, such as explaining something. I have a few ways I have dealt with the situation, they help a lot.

1. Most importantly is to mentally tell your self to slow down. This takes practice and even I fail sometimes. But when I do slow down, I definitely stutter less. (I noticed that if I get interrupted by my speaking partner, I will stutter more because now i am semi fighting him to finish my sentence). So gotta not worry about finishing your piece before he speaks.
2. I do breathing exercises, run and swim to enlarge my lungs. Not sure about you but when I stutter it feels like I am out of breath and can't finish that sentence.
3. Talk out loud when reading books or internet articles. Did you know the most famous Greek speaker Demosthenes beat his stuttering by chewing pebbles while speaking to the ocean? I am not suggestion you do same, as I haven't tried it either ;) but it demonstrates importance of talk out loud.

Link below:

https://www.google.com/amp/s/euroepinomics.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/the-pebbles-of-demosthenes-the-kings-speech-and-the-genetics-of-stuttering/amp/

Answer (score 1):

One technique I specifically find quite helpful is to take three (short) breaths in, and one long, slow breath out.  Followed by correctly saying the sentence that had tripped me up to begin with - sometimes slowly or with emphasis, depending on how badly I tangled it.  I've been using this technique so long I've forgotten where I found it, it works quite well for me.  Especially since it may not always be easy to step aside for a moment, as Alex Common mentioned.

This is a thoroughly unnatural breathing pattern, and takes a bit of concentration to boot, so it helps give a bit of distance and breathing room (ha!) from the conversation.  Between that and getting that darn sentence right, it usually calms me down enough to start speaking correctly again.  Speaking a bit more slowly and taking a little time, even half a second, to plan how I want to say my point helps keep it from happening again.

You may find other breathing patterns or self-distraction techniques useful, as well as or instead of what I described.  Even a single deep breath may be enough to help.  Or else maybe closing your eyes, and/or making some slow hand gesture, just somehow distracting yourself from the conversation for a second, just long enough to slow yourself down a bit. You can also look up meditation breathing or techniques, for visualizations to pair with such an exercise or other ideas that might speak to you better.

As a disclaimer, I don't stutter myself so can't say how it may or may not be useful for that, specifically.  I tend to use it because when I get overexcited I skip words or tangle my sentences, and generally trip myself up - and then get flustered, which doesn't help me untangle myself.